# XML Label ignore invalid character?

Tags: xml

this is my code

```
<info label="NOTE: For a new line add <br> in the text input."/>
```

The issue is, it picks up the "<" and ">" values and ends the info line for that attribute in the element line.

Is there a way to ignore that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out xml has a list of invalid characters. You can find the character here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

in my case, I have to do this

```
<info label="NOTE: For a new line add $lt;br&gt; in the text input."/>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: It should be `&lt;` instead of `$lt;`. I'm assuming that was just a typo on your part.